# No sound on Android when streaming audio in AIR

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm working on an app to stream audio from shoutcast. The streaming goes well on my computer and when debugging it with an Android-configuration.
But when I deploy it to an APK-file and run it on a Samsung Galaxy S, the streaming doesn't work.

My code for streaming the audio:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://.../;");
var soundContext:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(2000, true);
soundChannel = new SoundChannel();
sound = new Sound(urlRequest, soundContext);
soundChannel = sound.play();
```

I've also tried an addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE), it seems my app doesn't get there when running on a Samsung Galaxy.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check internet enabled descripted files.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html

Reffer Also

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Playing_mp3_files_on_Flex_Mobile-19106.html